# codeigniter 3 somente default url funciona

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um programa feito em PHP com codeIgniter. No meu controler tenho dois métodos, se coloco no arquivo routes.php assim `$route['default_controller'] = 'carta';`, chama a função index(). Porem se coloco `$route['default_controller'] = 'carta/elemento';`, ele chama o método elementos(). Porém, quero chamar o método elemento() não como default, mas pela url. Já tentei `$route['elementos'] = 'carta/elementos';`, mas quando tento acessar retorna para a pagina inicial.

Controller: `

```
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct ();
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model ( "carta_model" );

      }

    public function index() {
        $dados = array("nome" => "Hugo") ;
        $this->load->view("cartas/carta_view.php", array("dados" => $dados));


    }

    public function elementos() {
        $elementos = $this->carta_model->getElementos();
        $this->load->view("cartas/carta_view.php", array("elementos" => $elementos));

    }
} ?>`
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'carta';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['elementos'] = 'carta/elementos';
```

model:

```
<?php
class carta_model extends CI_model {

    public function getElementos() {


        return $this->db->get("elemento")->result_array();
    }


} ?>
```

view:

```
<?php  echo json_encode($dados);?>
```

arquivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi, `default controller` é o controlador padrão para quando você acessar sua URL. Se você coloca-lo como `$route['default_controller'] = 'home';` seu controlador será home e sempre acessará implicitamente o método index que é o padrão de todo `CI_Controller`, isso se aplica a todo e qualquer controller que derive de `CI_Controller`. Se você quiser que ele acesse um método direto como padrão use `$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index2';` por exemplo. As rotas com o Codeigniter funcionam assim `contoller/metodo/var1/var2/var3...`